# open and edit android system database using sqlite helper class with superuser permissions

Tags: android, sqlite, root

I am working on a fix for wifi in some android 4.1.2 devices. This requires me to edit the wifi_country_code field in the secure table in settings.db sqlite3 database file located in /data/data/com.android.providers.settings/databases/ directory.

I have the sqlite helper class to read, update, delete and insert records, but I cant use it to open and edit the file located in -> /data/data/com.android.providers.settings/databases/, as its a system file, for that I would need to get superuser pemissions.

I have already searched how to get superuser permissions for my app. I searched and found a [solution](http://muzikant-android.blogspot.com/2011/02/how-to-get-root-access-and-execute.html) to get the superuser permissions, and that works in getting me the superuser access, but I dont have any idea how to use it to perform my sqlite operations on the settings.db file located -> /data/data/com.android.providers.settings/databases/.

Comment: There is nothing more that you need.  SQLite does not implement permissions so if you can get access to the database file, you can edit it.

Comment: Agreed. Assuming that your app is running as superuser, it should be a matter of just opening the database at that path. However, you do not need `SQLiteOpenHelper`, as you are not creating the database. Just use `openDatabase()` on `SQLiteDatabase`. That being said, I have never written code that runs as superuser, so I may be missing some piece of the puzzle.

Comment: all right here is my code

'try {
     
     Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("su");
     
     SQLiteDatabase db = SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase("/data/data/com.android.providers.settings/databases/settings.db", null, SQLiteDatabase.OPEN_READWRITE);
        
    } catch (IOException e) {
     
     toastMessage(e.getMessage());
     
     //txtErrorMsg.setText(e.getMessage());
    }'

and this give me the error that permission is denied, even though in the toast message it says that my app has been granted superuser permissions




@CommonsWare